# Installing keyboard layouts from terminal

Tags: command-line, language-support

I'm building a docker container based on Ubuntu:14.04,
during the process of the container creation I would like to add several additional keyboard layouts (languages) support.

I assume that it's possible but I couldn't find how,
I'm using X11 CFXE4 desktop.

Suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "install" involved since all the layouts are made available via the `xkb-data` package (installed by default).

To set e.g. the *English (US)* and *French* keyboard layout:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'fr')]"
```